# php login page wont work

Tags: php, mysql

hye.. im newbie in php/mysql. can you help me, i'm getting 'wrong username or password' all the time.
here my login.php

```
<code>
    <table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
        <tr>
            <form method="post" action="checklogin.php">
                <td>
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3">
                                <strong>Member Login </strong>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="78">Username</td>
                            <td width="6">:</td>
                            <td width="294">
                                <input name="username" type="text" id="username"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Password</td>
                            <td>:</td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="password" type="password" id="password"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </form>
        </tr>
    </table>
</code>
```

and here my checklogin.php

```
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$username=stripslashes($username);
$password=stripslashes($password);
$username=mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password=mysql_real_escape_string($password);
$sql="SELECT user, pass FROM user_id WHERE user='$username' and pass='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count==1) {
    session_register("username");
    session_register("password");
    header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
    echo"Wrong Username or Password";
}
```

i have no problem with connecting to database, but i can't see where is the error. help me please.

Comment: This code is obsolete and has been for years. 1. mysql_* is deprecated. 2. session_register() is deprecated. 3. strip_slashes is unnecessary because magic_quotes is deprecated.

Comment: And 4. Indentation was introduced long ago

Comment: @Bojangles Might just be SO's formatting.

Comment: Are you sure you have the matching username password in the DB?

Comment: What's the value of $count? Is it more than 1? Is it null?

Comment: @FabienWarniez definitely not SO's fault.  I'll fix it in like 15 seconds

Comment: I meant, when you paste in SO, you still have to indent it, even though it may have been indented in their IDE.

Comment: i search this code in internet. i'm trying many code, but all fail. and at your point 1,2,3 what is 'deprecated'? can you tell me in other words? sorry, i'm poor in English. i'm trying to disable session register and strip_slashes. but it's still wont work.

Comment: lmgtfy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation Basically, those are outdated ways of doing things that may be insecure or no longer supported in the future.

Comment: deprecated means stop using it cuz it's old

Comment: Can you show us the content of your DB?

Comment: now i know what is deprecated. thanks.

Comment: my DB: table name = user_id and got 3 column = id, user, pass.

Comment: is your password hashed/or encrypted somehow during registration? if so, your `$_POST["password"]` won't match up

Comment: By the looks of your error message, your problem is most likely to be that, you're not passing DB connection. You may need to do something like: `$result=mysql_query($sql,$con);` and `$con` being your DB connection variable, if you are in fact using one. @user3259186 - I need to see what your DB connection looks like, in order to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of [`your comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491946/php-login-page-wont-work#comment32443181_21492130) regarding the following error messages:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\exa\checklogin.php on line 18
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\exa\checklogin.php on line 20

You seem to be mixing `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*` functions (your `checklogin.php` file contains `mysql_*` functions and your error messages are based on `mysqli_*`, as well as **storing passwords in plain text; this is extremely dangerous**, and you should consider using a different method, such as PHP's [`password()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) function.

I've put together a few versions for you, but there are a few things that stand at being deprecated.

For instance; [`session_register()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php)

> This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0

Therefore you may need to change:

```
session_register("username");
session_register("password");
```

to:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = 'username';
$_SESSION['password'] = 'password';
```

or:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = '$username';
$_SESSION['password'] = '$password';
```

However, I'm not entirely certain as to how you're using `session_register("username");` and `session_register("password");` in another file or not.

**MySQL_ version**

Assuming the following:

and I changed `$result=mysql_query($sql);` to `$result=mysql_query($sql,$con);` to pass DB connection to `$result`

```
<?php
session_start();
$db = mysql_connect("host","username", "password");

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('database_name', $db);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

$sql="SELECT user, pass FROM user_id WHERE user='$username' and pass='$password'";

if (mysql_query($sql, $con)) {
  echo ("Database query successful");
}else {
     die ("Database query failed: " .mysql_error());
}

$result=mysql_query($sql,$con);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count==1) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = '$username';
    $_SESSION['password'] = '$password';
    header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
```

---

**MySQLi_ version**

```
<?php
session_start();
$con=mysqli_connect("host","username", "password", "database_name");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())   {  
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); }

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);

$sql="SELECT user, pass FROM user_id WHERE user='$username' and pass='$password'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count==1) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = '$username';
    $_SESSION['password'] = '$password';
    header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
```

---

**login_success.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){ 
header("location:login.php"); 
}
?>

<html>
<body>
Login Successful
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, but i tried but still got error. i'm also edit my post with full code. hope you can help me.

Comment: You're welcome. Can you tell me which error you're getting? @user3259186

Comment: this is the error : Warning: stripslashes() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\exa\checklogin.php on line 15

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\exa\checklogin.php on line 15

Warning: stripslashes() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\exa\checklogin.php on line 16

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\exa\checklogin.php on line 16
Wrong Username or Password

Comment: by disabling '//$username = mysqli_real_escape_string(stripslashes($con,$_POST['username']));
//$password = mysqli_real_escape_string(stripslashes($con,$_POST['password']));
' and replace with '$username = ($_POST['username']);
$password = ($_POST['password']);' i'm manage to go page login_succes.php but the page only show blank page.

Comment: Ok, then change that to `$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['username']);` and `$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);` you don't need `stripslashes` since `mysqli_real_escape_string` is already taking care of any illegal characters. @user3259186 and id you use my example for DB connection also? The `$con` parameter is for your DB connection.

Comment: great. i'm following your guide, also manage to go to login_success.php. but the page still empty. it's is about session?

Comment: Yes. I noticed you added some new code. This line `if(!session_is_registered(username)){` should be more like `if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){` @user3259186

Comment: You could do this: `if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){ header("location:exa_mysql.php"); } else{ echo "You are logged in"; }` @user3259186

Comment: Login Successful :) but y dont redirect to other page?

Comment: Which other page? `exa_mysql.php` or other file? If other file then you need to do `if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){ header("location:exa_mysql.php"); } else{ header("location:success_page.php"); }` @user3259186

Comment: Plus, the way you edited your question with `<html>` etc. on top of `session_start();` you will get an error message. @user3259186 You should **not** have edited your question using **my code**. It's not right. I'm not going to help you any further.

Comment: I did what we call a "rollback" to your original question/code. Your original question must contain your original code and not borrowed code from an answer given in order for others to potentially get the credit, yet alone "my" code that I wrote to "help" you. Should you rollback to a version that contains my code, I will flag the question and let SO know of the activity. I am pretty sure they will vote in my favor and potentially close your account. @user3259186 - That's not how things are done around here, stealing my work and to call it your own.

Comment: i'm sorry. i didn't means that. my apologies. im trying to rollback my question. just before, i thought easier for you to know my problem. btw. thanks a lot for your help. you really save me bro.

Comment: again, i'm really sorry. it's not me want to stealing your work. thanks for help me rolling back the origin question. sorry again, and much thanks for your help.

Comment: and for clicking the white checkmark, what is that? i cant vote any yet. :(

Comment: It's not "voting" it's "accepting" as correct answer. When you click on the white checkmark under the up/down arrow, it will turn green. That is how a question is considered "answered/closed". @user3259186

Comment: done. thanks a lot again. sorry, i'm just newbie. not so familiar with this situation. thanks again for helping and guide me to fix my problem until its solve. you all are nice and great.

Answer (score 0):

do a `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors','on');` in the first line of your file so that php starts talking.

Are you having a table named as `user_id` or is it a typo?

```
$sql="SELECT user, pass FROM user_id WHERE user='$username' and pass='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Anyway, as a rule in programming, never assume the output of a function. Always check its return value `$result` before anything else:

```
if(!$result) die(mysql_error());
```

Now you will know if there is any sql error itself. And then you can solve your problem. Rest of the code is fine for the first day in php. You can learn the other 1..4 points tomorrow after you are with today.

Comment: user_id is my table name. thanks for the 'error_reporting(E_ALL); and ini_set('display_errors','on');' tips, now i can see the problem line. but i'm still trying to fix it. my login page still not working.

Comment: which one is the problem line?

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\exa\checklogin.php on line 18

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\exa\checklogin.php on line 20